# Symfony - Add several forms in a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, image, symfony

I'm working on **Symfony**, I have a relationship: **Product - OneToMany - Image**.
I want in my add product form,  **add 4 Image**.

I know how to do it it with JavaScript (By adding dynamically inputs with the pattern...), but I would like to do it in my form, but I don't know how...

Here's my code:

**ProductType.php**

```
class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Titre'))
            ->add('url', UrlType::class, array('label' => 'URL'))
            ->add('client', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Client'))
            ->add('description', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Description'))
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AntoinePortfolioBundle:Category',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Catégories'))
            ->add('tags', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AntoinePortfolioBundle:Tag',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Tags'))
            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ImageType::class));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Antoine\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Project'
        ));
    }
}
```

**ImageType.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Antoine\PortfolioBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom'))
            ->add('alt', TextType::class, array('label' => 'alt'))
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Image'));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Antoine\PortfolioBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }
}
```

My relationships work, this is not ne problem.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using form events. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

I think `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` will work.

Comment: Thank you but I already wrote a JavaScript script, actually it does work well.
Thanks for this link too, I'll check it out !